# Two successes after an openCursor

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Can I bind two functions to the onsuccess event of an openCursor?
I would like to do this in order to populate the initial values that are in the first row.

```js
;(function() {
 var variables = {}
 
 var myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'])
 var myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
 var myIndex = myObjectStore.index('myIndex')
 var myRange = IDBKeyRange.only(0)
 var myRequest = myIndex.openCursor(myRange)
 myRequest.onsuccess = firstRow // This is what I'm wondering about
 myRequest.onsuccess = mySuccess // Can I have two onsuccess events?
 
 function firstRow(response) {
  var result = response.target.result
  if (result) {
   variables.custid = result.value.custid
   // Notice there's no result.continue() here
  }
 }
 function mySuccess(response) {
  var result = response.target.result
  if (result) {
   if (result.value.custid === variables.custid) {
    // yay
   }
   result.continue()
  }
 }
}())
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. onsuccess is, generally, just syntax sugar for adding an event listener. The main difference is that setting onsuccess overwrites all other event listeners, whereas adding an event listener using the proper syntax does not. Your code will not work because setting onsuccess a second time just overwrites the first listener.

Try the following:

```
function foo() {
  var request = store.openCursor();
  request.addEventListener('success', firstListenerFunction);
  request.addEventListener('success', secondListenerFunction);
}
```

There is no guarantee regarding which listener will be notified first. Generally it will be the first listener because most implementations notify listeners in registration order. But this isn't guaranteed.

Also, both listeners will be notified every single time. Keep in mind the performance impact.

Various indexedDB API objects like IDBRequest basically inherit from the class EventTarget. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) is some useful reading for learning about EventTarget. EventTarget is used all over the place.